# I am trying to install selenium standalone

Tags: selenium

I am trying to install selenium standalone using this command in vs code:

```
selenium-standalone install
```

But it shows the following error:

```
 **

selenium-standalone install    selenium-standalone : The term 'selenium-standalone' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or    operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was    included, verify that    the path is correct and try again.    At line:1 char:1    + selenium-standalone install    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (selenium-standalone:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException****strong text****

**
```

Comment: you need to put the folder where selenium-standalone inside to PATH environment variable

Comment: @yong I tired it but still doesn't work :/

Comment: could you tell me where you get this command guide to install selenium standalone?

Comment: here is the source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-standalone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install the selenium-standalone as global package, then append the global package install folder into your PATH Envirormen Variable.

1. execute  'npm install -g selenium-standalone'
2. execute  'npm config get prefix', it will print out a folder path, copy this path and open 'Envirormen Variable' setting dialog from Windows control panel or right menu: 'Properties' of 'My Computer'.
3. Add a semicolon at the end of current value of 'PATH' Envirormen Variable, then append above path.
4. Open new terminal to execute 'selenium-standalone install' (Don't execute the command on old opened terminal)

[image]